# How to restore data from a deleted app that uses iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, time-machine

I deleted an app that stores data in iCloud. Then I wanted to restore the data by using Time Machine on my Mac with macOS 13.2. Unfortunately, when I started Time Machine in the iCloud folder, it does not show me the folder of the deleted app, not even for previous times.

How can I restore an iCloud folder of a deleted app with Time Machine to a different location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In navigated to `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/` in Finder. Then I started Time Machine from there. Within Time Machine, I could navigate into this folder and I saw a list of all folders that were previously hidden.

However, restoring the desired directory was tricky as well because it was restored by default to the original folder, which was and is not visible.

The trick is to tap on the little button with the circle and the three dots and then select “Restore Cryptomator to…“ (see screenshot below).

[image: Time Machine Restore To…]